# Vue 2 to 3 upgrading a library with webpack

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vuejs3

We are in the process of migrating from Vue 2 to Vue 3 for our internal Design System. As the Design System is installed in a web application, naturally we have set Vue to be a peer dependency in the Design System. Also, when we bundle the Design System, we have specified `vue` as an external library. This is causing webpack to bundle the Vue functions like so in the Design System

```
// EXTERNAL MODULE: external "vue"
var external_vue_ = __webpack_require__(748);
...
const _hoisted_1 = (0,external_vue_.createTextVNode)("Actions");
```

The problem here is that when the Design System is imported into the Web application, it complians that `external_vue_` is undefined because Vue 3.x no longer has a default export. Any ideas on how this can be resolved? I am assuming this is a webpack change but I am not certain.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare an external dependency in webpack, you can choose the library type.

For `vue3`, perhaps the `module` type would work.

Here is the syntax:

```js
module.exports = {
  //...
  externals: {
    vue: 'module vue',
  },
};

// or

module.exports = {
  //...
  externals: {
    vue: 'commonjs vue',
  },
};
```

View more information here: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/